# Item CheckingIn event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

---

I have a document library. When I upload a document and try to check in the same, I get the following error.

0x81072186 An event receiver has canceled the request.

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x81072186):         0x81072186An event receiver has canceled the request.]

Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CheckInFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Int32 iCheckinType, String bstrCheckinComment, Boolean bIsMigrate, Int32 iEditorId, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +0

Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CheckInFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Int32 iCheckinType, String bstrCheckinComment, Boolean bIsMigrate, Int32 iEditorId, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +195

[SPException: An event receiver has canceled the request.]

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.CheckIn(String comment, SPCheckinType checkInType, Boolean bIsMigrate, SPUser modifiedBy) +27676034

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.CheckIn(String comment, SPCheckinType checkInType) +21

Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Checkin.ExecuteAction() +686

Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Checkin.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +2001

System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66

### System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if an Event Receiver has been added to the library or to the Content Type and that it for some reason rejects the checkin.

You can use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) to find out what/where the event receiver is.